# Crear matriz de coordenadas en Python

Tags: python

necesito hacer una matriz de coordenadas del tipo:

```
(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)
(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)
(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```py
matrix = []
sub_matrix = [0, 0]
for i in range(1, 4):
    for a in range(1, 4):
        sub_matrix[0] = i
        sub_matrix[1] = a
        matrix.append(sub_matrix)
print(matrix)
```

obtengo como resultado:

```
[[3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3]]
```

El parcial se corresponde con lo pedido si se pone print(sub_matrix), pero al final de cada ciclo cambia el resto de los elementos de la matriz en lugar de agregarlo al final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al hacer lo que haces simplemente los valores se reemplazan y por eso queda solo el último, que es `3`, te recomiendo mejor trabajar con tuplas, pues será lo más cercano a tu ejemplo

```py
matriz = []

#recorremos 
for i in range(1,4):
    for a in range(1,4):
        matriz.append((i,a))#agregamos directamente los datos como tuplas
```

Aquí al tener los datos como typlas `(i,a)` nos pomos ahorrar la creación de otra variable, y al ya estar agrupada solo la añadimos directamente a la lista.

**resultado**

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Recuerda que en python no existen los arrays solo las listas y no es necesario especificar el índice del dato, por lo que también podemos hacer esto

```py
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1,4):
        sub= [i,j]
        matriz.append(sub)
```

El resultado será el mismo

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

No quería poner esta forma, por que tal vez te va a confundir pero es mucho más fácil y rápido, además es solo una línea de código

```py
matriz = [(i,a) for i in range(1,4) for a in range(1,4)]
```

Esto se llama compresión de lista y hace los mismo que tu ciclo `for` primero itera `i` en el rango de `1-4` y luego itera `a` en el mismo rango, en cada iteracion se agrega `(i,a)` a la lista de `matriz`
El resultado sigue siendo el mismo

```py
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: gracias!!! Funciono perfecto!

Comment: De nada,  recuerda que puedes aceptar la respuesta, así otras personas la tendrán como guía al momento de presentar un problema similar

Answer (score 2):

suponiendo que buscas un resultado en la forma de matriz:

```
[[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],
 [(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)],
 [(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]]
```

entonces(retocando el codigo de @Christian):

```
matriz = []
for i in range(1,4):
    matriz+=[[]]
    for j in range(1,4):
        matriz[i-1]+=[(i,j)]

print(matriz)
# [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)], [(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]]
```

Comment: Gracias!!! La respuesta que buscaba fue la de Christian, pero me sirve tambien.

Answer (score 0):

Código:

```
for a in range(4) :
    for b in range(4) :
        print(f"({a},{b})",end=" ") 
    print()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]